# Oracle times ten embedded in a java application

Tags: java, database, oracle, embedded-database, timesten

Can someone point to me some documentation on how to run the Oracle times ten database in an embedded mode within a java application?

I would like to run times-ten as a replacement for HSQLDB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oracle does not as far as I know have an embedded mode for Java programs.  What you most likely want is the Oracle JDBC driver to talk to a Oracle server "somewhere".

Another approach which might be valid for you, is running your code inside the JVM running in most modern Oracle installations.

Comment: He is talking about TimesTen, which is embedded database that can act as a local cache to Oracle database supporting local queries and write-through updates.

Answer (score 0):

While the Oracle TimesTen In-Memory Database 11g [Overview](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/timesten/overview/index.html) mentions the word "embedded":

> Oracle TimesTen In-Memory Database is
>   a memory-optimized relational database
>   that empowers applications with the
>   instant responsiveness and very high
>   throughput required by today's
>   real-time enterprises and industries
>   such as telecom, capital markets, and
>   defense. **Deployed in the application
>   tier as an embedded** or standalone
>   **database**, Oracle TimesTen In-Memory
>   Database operates on databases that
>   fit entirely in physical memory using
>   standard SQL interfaces. It can also
>   be used as an in-memory database cache
>   for the Oracle database to enhance the
>   response time and throughput of user
>   applications.

I couldn't find obvious instructions in the [product documentation](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E13085_01/doc/index.htm). I'll let you dig it deeper :)